# How to add search results 'no results found' text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show a text when there are no results. I know how to get that text and make sure it is dynamic, but I do not know how I can add it to the SearchResultCell (because that is where the results are being shown when there are items).

```
  child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, bottom: 15),
      height: 50,
      child: SearchResultCell(
        search: this._search[index],
      ))
```

I can't use children, because container does not allow it + I have to put the text in the `SearchResultCell`, but don't know how.

Comment: what is `SearchResultCell` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use children by doing this,

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, bottom: 15),
                  height: 50,
                  child: Column(
                    children:
                    SearchResultCell(
                      search: this._search[index],
                    ),
                    //another widget
                  )
              )
```

Comment: As in: how? Where is the text and how do I show it when there are NO results?

Comment: can you show me more of your code ?